# Missing date column from interactivity callback

Tags: carto

I can't seem to get "date" columns to return for popups/infoWindows. I can retrieve other data types without an issue. I have the interactivity set correctly from what I can tell, but the featureClick callback only returns one column.

My code relies on v2 of the CartoDB API.

Here's my call to cartoDB.createLayer:

cartodb.createLayer( map, { type : "cartodb", options : layerData } )

where layerData is

```
interactivity: "name,admin_date,size"
query: "SELECT size, name, admin_date, the_geom_webmercator FROM book1"
table_name: "book1"
tile_style: "#book1{marker-width:5;marker-opacity: 0.9;marker-line-color: white;marker-fill:#e6e6e6;marker-line-width: 1;marker-line-opacity: 0.9;marker-placement: point;marker-type: ellipse;marker-allow-overlap: true;} #book1{[size>=0]{marker-fill:#b8cde9;}[size>=18229430]{marker-fill:#6693cc;}[size>=22061458]{marker-fill:#2f5f9d;}}"
user_name: "c2es"
```

The featureClick callback only return the first and last columns. Any ideas what's wrong?

Answer (score 2):

This is due to a bug that doesn't allow to represent date columns in the interactions.

It is a bug already reported here: https://github.com/CartoDB/Windshaft/issues/103

As a workaround, you can cast the date column to text like this:

```
sql: "SELECT size, name, admin_date::text, the_geom_webmercator FROM book1"
```